# How to compare slope of two time series

Tags: time-series

Suppose we have the 2 sets of time series data L1,M1 sampled at the same 1000 points of time t[t1,t2,...t1000]. Lets assume before hand that that the L1 can be given as 
L1 = tX+a where X is the slope and a is the noise

and M1 can be give as
M1 = tY+b

Now I want to know how to formulate a parameter that measures the difference between slopes of L1 and M1 from their respective 1000 sampled points.

I am a novice when it comes to statistics, so any help or hints would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: I guess you want to calculate the Correlation coefficient which is a numerical measure of some type of correlation, meaning a statistical relationship between two variables. The variables may be two columns of a given data set of observations, often called a sample, or two components of a multivariate random variable with a known distribution.

Comment: The global slope? If so you could obtain that from a linear model.

Comment: @Gal Dreiman I have already tried to measure correlation coefficient. It doesnt measure what you think it does. at least it doesnt measure what I want to measure. even for the above linear function, irrespective of the difference between X and Y, correlation coefficient is always 1.

Comment: @Kanmani, please help me to better understand what you need - you need to just know the difference between the two slopes?

Comment: @GalDreiman yes, I want a parameter that measures the difference between the slopes. For example, let the parameter be names Z. So if X=10, y=5 and if Z is a', the Z should a' when X=20, y=10 (because in both cases the slope X is double the slope Y)

Comment: so basically you want to calculate for `a_1X+b_1` and `a_2Y+b_2` the |a_1 - a_2|  ?

Comment: I would just do a linear regression with the models you've got already, then calculate $|X-Y|.$